# TestNG XML with groups and packages not working

Tags: selenium, annotations, testng

I am working on a set of selenium tests I want to run using a TestNG XML.

```xml
<suite name="MATS">
    <parameter name="browser" value="firefox" />
    <parameter name="platform" value="windows" />
    <test name="mats_test">
        <groups>
           <run>
              <include name = "mats" />
           </run>
        </groups>

        <packages>
            <package name="com.sel.tests.app.set1.*" /> 
            <package name="com.sel.tests.app.set2.*" />
            <package name="com.sel.tests.app.set3.*" /> 
        </packages>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Directly under each of those packages there are multiple classes with the `@Test(groups = { "mats" })` annotation on top. However, I get this output:

```
MATS
Total tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
```

Update: Ok, so cleaning the project didn't work so I imported it again in a new workspace after which it seems to be working. Closing the question. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Could you create an issue on https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues or even better pull-request a new test case (and why not a fix)? :)

Comment: Thanks. I already see a couple of very similar issues reported. Will try out a few ideas/workarounds and will close the question if that works.

Comment: Does it work if you replace the content under `<test>` with `<classes><class name="..."></classes>`?

Comment: Yep. The issue is for some reason TL;DR to mention, I had to organize one test case per class and I do not want to mention the class name directly in the XML.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working in IntelliJ Idea try to select in main menu Run -> Edit Configurations. On left side select "TestNG" configuration, on right side select "In whole project" radio button and Working Directory: as $MODULE_DIR$ (or play with that)